# how to prenvent an existed name to rewrite

Tags: java, arraylist, treeset

i have a problem that i want when i enter a name of library in nameText (type Text ) and the name already existed in the list of libraries, the button ok is blocked und i cannot do that (a messsage displays and informs that i would write another name )

i don´t know exactly what i use treeSet or arrayList and how??
the code is:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(List list)  
{  
    Set set = new HashSet();  
    List newList = new ArrayList();  
    for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {  
        Object element = iter.next();  
        if (set.add(element))  
            newList.add(element);  
    }  
    list.clear();  
    list.addAll(newList);  
}
```

in the context:

```
 public class EditLibraryDialog extends Dialog implements ItemListener {

ILibrary library;
Text pathText;
Text nameText;
static boolean okPressed;

public EditLibraryDialog(Shell parent) {
    super(parent);
    library = null;
}

public EditLibraryDialog(Shell parent, ILibrary library) {
    super(parent);
    this.library = library;
}

public ILibrary getLibrary() {
    return library;
}

public boolean open() {
    return open(null);
}

public boolean open(String message) {

    final Shell parent = getParent();
    final Shell dialog = new Shell(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM
            | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    okPressed = false;

    dialog.setSize(700, 150);
    dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    dialog.setLayoutData(gridData);

    Label l;

    if (message != null) {
        l = new Label(dialog, SWT.NULL);
        l.setText(message);
    }

    l = new Label(dialog, SWT.NULL);

    l.setText("Name");

    nameText = new Text(dialog, SWT.BORDER);

    l = new Label(dialog, SWT.NULL);
    l = new Label(dialog, SWT.NULL);
    l = new Label(dialog, SWT.NULL);
    l.setText("Path");

    pathText = new Text(dialog, SWT.BORDER);

    });

    if (library == null) {
        dialog.setText("Add Library");
    } else {
        dialog.setText("Edit Library");
        nameText.setText(library.getName());
        pathText.setText(library.getPath());
    }

    final Button okButton = new Button(dialog, SWT.PUSH);
    okButton.setText("Ok");
    GridData gridData4 = new GridData(GridData.END, GridData.CENTER, false,
            false);
    gridData4.horizontalSpan = 3;
    gridData4.horizontalIndent = 20;
    okButton.setLayoutData(gridData4);
    okButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            String id;
            if (library != null) {
                id = library.getId();
            } else {
                id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            }
            library = new LibraryFactory().create(id, nameText.getText(),
                    pathText.getText());
            dialog.dispose();
            okPressed = true;



    }});




    nameText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        String lastValidText = "";

        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            // avoid setting invalid values for the name text field
            String textValue = ((Text) e.getSource()).getText();
            if (parseName(textValue)) {
                lastValidText = textValue;
                okButton.setEnabled(textValue.equals("") ? false : true);
            } else {
                nameText.setText(lastValidText);
            }
        }

    });

    nameText.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w| ]*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(e.text);
            e.doit = matcher.matches();

        }
    });

    pathText.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.-\\\\\\/\\$]*");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(e.text);
            e.doit = matcher.matches();
        }
    });

    Button cancelButton = new Button(dialog, SWT.PUSH);
    cancelButton.setText("Cancel");

    cancelButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });


      public static void removeDuplicates(List list)  
      {  
        Set set = new HashSet();  
        List newList = new ArrayList();  
        for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {  
          Object element = iter.next();  
          if (set.add(element))  
            newList.add(element);  
        }  
        list.clear();  
        list.addAll(newList);  
      }  




    if (nameText.getText().equals(""))
        okButton.setEnabled(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Existed Library"); }


    dialog.open();
    Display display = parent.getDisplay();
    while (!dialog.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    return okPressed;
}

private boolean parseName(String newText) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
      }
```

Comment: Please trim down to relevant part for what is needed to reproduce your problem. Nobody will want to wade through this much code.

Comment: I don't really get what you want, or where the problem is, but duplicates are already removed in `public static void removeDuplicates(List list)`

Comment: @Theolodis  the method public static void removeDuplicates(List list) don´t  run , i try to modify it , can you help me how add or remove to make it work

Comment: @Tichodroma i want to add a method that i can verify when i add a new name (in nameText) that the name exist or no, if it don´t existed , it will be added to the list of libraries else i must modify this name

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList` or `Vector` and check using the `contains` method.

```
 Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
 v.add("apple");
 v.add("mango");

 if(v.contains("apple")) {
     //element already in list, do something
 }
 else {
     //element not in list, do something
 }
```

Comment: have you an example? , because i am new in java

Comment: please help me , i want to use your Idee but i don´t know how